# Azure Blob File Download through Azure API Management Fails with error - BackendConnectionFailure: at transfer-response

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement that should allow user to allow download file through Azure Blob Storage. I am not supposed to expose the blob storage or generate SAS for a file and expose it to end user. So for this purpose i have used API Management and in the inbound policy i am generating SAS and forming the complete URL for blob download and setting it as Backend service.

Eg: After the backend service is formed it will look like this

```
https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.zip?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=fceSGjsjsuswsZk1yv0Db7EYo%3D&st=2020-02-14T12%3A36%3A13Z&se=2020-03-15T12%3A41%3A13Z&sp=r
```

I am able to download files with size of 14 GB through API Management with a through put of 10MBPS. But I also want to download a file that is of size 200 GB. When i try to download this file, the download is initiated and i am able to download some content but after a while it fails with below error. And during the download the max throughput achieved is 10 MBPS.

[image]

After I check App Insight log for this failure, i see following error - `BackendConnectionFailure: at transfer-response, Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` It seems that this error means there was a problem at blob storage but does not exactly state what it could be.

If i use the actual SAS url that is generated out of API Management and download file. The downloads completes with a much higher throughput of 90 MBPS.

I have not set any bandwidth limit or download limit using policy in APIM.

I am trying to check if there is any default setting that is preventing this file to be downloaded either on Blob or on APIM? And also trying to figure out why the throughput is so low when i download the file using APIM.

Note: I am using an Azure VM with good configuration and using curl to test my API.

Comment: Maybe the SAS Token has a limited lifetime. If so, after the token is invalid the blob storage will terminate the cnnection. For your large file it is possible the lifetime is too short.

Comment: @KirKone Even though the lifetime is kept short. After the download is started from Blob storage will not terminate the on going download if it is started before the expiry time. Only if there is a network issue and there is a retry made that time token expiry is checked.